# popperJS: Multiple popups on element

Tags: javascript, popper.js

I would like to place a variable number of popups on an element and I considered using [PopperJS](https://popper.js.org/) to manage the placement of the popups, however I have only ever seen popperJS used with a single popup.
PopperJS does have an [offset modifier](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/offset/) which accepts a function, so maybe I could use this?

I would like the popups placed around the element, like petals on a flowers, but I would like a reusable function that can work with any number of items.

I have created [a little test on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-leavitt-xd137u?file=/src/index.js) - I will keep working on it and tidy it up.

Do you understand what I am trying to do? Is PopperJS the right approach for this?

Thanks